# Razor Conditional In Foreach

Tags: razor-2

What's wrong this snippet?

I'm getting a "Text cannot appear within..." error

If you cut out the if statement the code's fine.

```
<ul>
@foreach(MenuItem item in @Model.MenuItems)
{
  String controller = item.Controller;
  String activeCss = "";

  if (item.IsActive)
  {
        activeCss = "active"
  }

  <li>
        @HTML.ActionLink()
  </li>

}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you posting the actual code? There are several problems with the one you posted, but this should work:

```
<ul>
@foreach(MenuItem item in Model.MenuItems) // No need for @ before Model inside code.
{
  String controller = item.Controller;
  String activeCss = "";

  if (item.IsActive)
  {
        activeCss = "active"; // Added ; here.
  }

  <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Action", "Controller")
        // Html should not be upper-case, ActionLink requires arguments.
  </li>

}
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, that was my actual code. I'll try out your changes this evening.